# How rewrite Longmore LJ in *Salt v Stratstone Specialist Ltd* (2015) without negator?

Tags: legalese, negative-polarity-items

To improve English, I want try re-rewriting long sentences without negator because I understand ["Don't you ever talk like that to me again", but not "Don't you never silence like that to me never"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15336/5306).

Poole, Shaw-Mellors. [*Contract Law Concentrate* (4 ed 2019)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Concentrate-Jill-Pool/dp/0198840446/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 209.

> *Leaf v International Galleries* (1950): picture
>   represented (non-fraudulent) to be ‘Salisbury
>   Cathedral’ by Constable. Five years later the
>   purchaser attempted to sell it and discovered it
>   was not by Constable. The Court of Appeal (CA)
>   held that rescission had been lost as not exercised
>   within a reasonable time. However, some
>   doubt has been cast on *Leaf v International
>   Galleries* (1950) by the Court of Appeal in
>   *Salt v Stratstone Specialist Ltd* (2015) where
>   Longmore LJ stated:

p 210.

> > ‘It must, moreover,
> >     be remembered that Leaf was decided well
> >     before the Misrepresentation Act was passed. 
> >     **It must be doubtful whether since the enactment
> >     of [section 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misrepresentation_Act_1967#Section_1) it is still good law that a representor
> >     should be in no worse position than if the
> >     representation had become a term of the
> >     contract, particularly if the representor takes no
> >     steps to prove that he was not negligent.**’

"It must be doubtful whether since the enactment of section 1 it is still good law" just means Longmore thinks opposite. I can just add NOT.

> a representor should NOT be in no worse position than if the representation had become a term of the contract, particularly if the representor takes no steps to prove that he was not negligent.

Now how rewrite without "NOT" and "no worse"? Does "NOT be in no worse position" mean better?

> a representor should be in BETTER position than if the representation had become a term of the contract, particularly if the representor takes no steps to prove that he was not negligent.

I quote 2 other books for context for you. [*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p 237.

> 9.42 Leaf involved a wholly innocent misrepresentation, where some indulgence to the representor
>   can be expected. Perhaps it is only in such cases that Lord Denning’s view
>   should prevail over conflicting considerations of fairness to the representee. Recently
>   the Court of Appeal in *Salt v Stratstone Specialist Ltd* (2015) has pointed out that Leaf
>   is out of date—it reflected the principle that the misrepresentation regime should not
>   give greater protection to a purchaser than if the statement had been incorporated as a
>   term of the contract, and at the time the Sale of Goods Act provided that a purchaser
>   would be deemed to have accepted the goods if he did not reject them within a reasonable
>   time. Since then, amendments to the Sale of Goods Act, and the enactment of the
>   Misrepresentation Act, cast doubt on the reasoning and conclusion in *Leaf*, therefore the
>   court in *Salt*, although unable to overrule the earlier Court of Appeal decision, doubted
>   that lapse of time alone should generally bar rescission.

Mindy Chen-Wishart. [*Contract Law* (2018 6 edn)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Mindy-Chen-Wishart/dp/0198806353/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 228.

> But even if the representee remains ignorant
>   of the non-fraudulent misrepresentation, it was once thought that a substantial
>   passage of time may itself bar rescission. In *Leaf v International Galleries* (1950), L was
>   induced to buy a picture of Salisbury Cathedral by I’s innocent misrepresentation that
>   it was painted by the famous artist Constable. L only discovered this was false when
>   he tried to sell the picture some five years later. Nevertheless, L’s claim to rescind the
>   contract was denied due to lapse of time. Jenkins LJ said that contracts ‘cannot be
>   kept open and subject to the possibility of rescission indefinitely’. In addition, the
>   representor should not be worse off than if the statement had become a term, when
>   the representee would be barred from termination if she had ‘accepted’ the goods
>   under the Sale of Goods Act 1893. This was questioned by the Court of Appeal in
>   *Salt v Stratstone Specialist Ltd* (2015), since section 1 MA allows a representee to treat
>   a term as a representation (5.2.2.1).

Comment: Hi Elaine Nai! "...a representor should NOT be in no worse position"  means that the representor should be in worse position. If that is meant (which, of course, is not likely), then I don't see the reason (even in a legalese context, which requires a high level of verbal precision) to use that phrase instead of the simpler "should be in worse position". It is more likely of course that the intended meaning is "the representor should be in no worse position" . This means in equal or better position than..  It is not the same of  course as saying "should be in better position"

Comment: If your passage is stripped off the material unrelated to your question you could gloss it as "The requirement that the representor should be in no worse position is doubtful"

Comment: "Better" does not mean "no worse". It means actually *better*. That's a completely different thing to say. I'd abstain from rewording legalese passages. Quote them exactly as they are and move on.

Comment: *To improve English* That is indeed a noble aim; the way C21 is going the language needs all help it can get.  Perhaps, though, you meant something closer to *To improve my English* ?

Comment: I think your link should be to [the judgement itself](https://www.casemine.com/judgement/uk/5a8ff70360d03e7f57ea5b86/amp) (and paragraph 34) rather than to the Amazon page for the book.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

> It must be doubtful whether since the enactment of section 1 it is still good law that a representor should be in no worse position than if the representation had become a term of the contract, particularly if the representor takes no steps to prove that he was not negligent.

The *since* here means *after*: "Now that section 1 has been enacted", and it forms part of a parenthetical phrase:

> It must be doubtful whether, since the enactment of section 1, ...
>   Now that section 1 has been enacted, it must be doubtful whether it is still good law...

Since that phrase is merely providing context, it could be omitted.

The rest might be simplified as

> It might not be good law that the representor should be at least as well off as he would be if the representation had been in the contract, particularly if he does not attempt to prove that he was not negligent.

There may be a better word than "not negligent", which would remove the double negative.

What you cannot do is simply insert a *not* into a sentence!

> a representor should NOT be in no worse position

...especially when that introduces its own double negative and actually means that a representor should actually be in a worse position. The judgement doesn't say that: it says that it's **doubtful** that a representor should be in **no worse** position, that is, it's doubtful that he should be no worse off, or it is likely that he should be worse off.

Judgements are nuanced: your simplification removes the nuance. The judge actually said that it's likely that the representor should be worse off, he didn't say that he definitely should be worse off.

> It might be that the representor should be worse off than he would be if the representation had been in the contract, particularly if he does not attempt to prove that he was not negligent.